# Adding ul class to function output

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class, html-lists

I have function. It shows like that.

```
    <div id="sidebar-category"><h2 class="sidebar-title black">Konular</h2>     <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2"><a href="http://www.domain.com/cats/girisimler/" >Girişimler</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="http://www.domain.com/cats/isletme-yonetimi/" >İşletme Yönetimi</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://www.domain.com/cats/proje-yonetimi/" >Proje Yönetimi</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="http://www.domain.com/cats/web-dunyasi/" >Web Dünyası</a>
</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

How can I add class in `<ul>` ?

This is my function :

```
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Home right sidebar',
        'id'            => 'home_right_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="sidebar-category">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="sidebar-title black">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

I show HTML with this code

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using WordPress. Can you edit the ul in the widget to add the class manually? If not, you could always use jQuery (present in WordPress) to add a class:

```
$('#sidebar-category ul').addClass('myClass');
```

Be sure it loads after the dom is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar-category ul').addClass('myClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just using the default wordpress 'Categories' widget? It looks like you can't directly edit the ul element in anyway. According this: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php

You would need to either use jQuery like derekcbaldwin suggested or write your own widget/extend the categories widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in following two ways:

1. Using JS/JQuery | As mentioned above, but it will fail in the browsers without javascript enabled which is a rare case.
2. Using Output Buffer | The PHP way

USING JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#sidebar-category ul').addClass('your-class-name');
});
```

USING PHP OUTPUT BUFFERING:

In your sidebar.php or where you used the sidebar output function dynamic_sidebar( 'your-sidebar' ) use the below given code:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar( 'your-sidebar' );
    $sidebar_output = ob_get_clean();
    $ul_class = 'your-class-name';
    echo apply_filters( 'widget_output', $sidebar_output, $ul_class );
?>
```

In functions.php file add a filter hook to widget_output that will add class to UL:

```
<?php

    function widget_output_processor( $widget_output, $ul_class ) {

        $widget_output = str_replace('<ul>', '<ul class="'.$ul_class.'">', $widget_output);
        return $widget_output;

    }
    add_filter( 'widget_output', 'widget_output_processor', 10, 2 );

?>
```